# Angular drag and drop file to a specific div

Tags: angular

I created custom drag and drop in Angular.
Everything works fine, but here is one problem. Drag and drop works for whole screen. **I want it to be limited to just a specific div, not to whole screen.**

component.ts

```
  // Dragover listener
  @HostListener('dragover', ['$event']) onDragOver(evt: any) {    
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
    this.coverPhotoOver = true;
  }

  // Dragleave listener
  @HostListener('dragleave', ['$event']) public onDragLeave(evt: any) {    
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
    this.coverPhotoOver = false;
  }

  // Drop listener
  @HostListener('drop', ['$event']) public ondrop(evt: any) {    
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
    this.coverPhotoOver = false;
    let files = evt.dataTransfer.files;
    if (files.length > 0) {
      this.onCoverPhotoDropped(files[0]);
    }
  }

  onCoverPhotoDropped(selectedCoverPic: any) {
    this.selectedCoverPic = selectedCoverPic;
    this.coverPicName = this.selectedCoverPic.name;

    var ext = this.selectedCoverPic.name.substring(
      this.selectedCoverPic.name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1
    );
    if (
      ext.toLowerCase() == 'jpg' ||
      ext.toLowerCase() == 'jpeg' ||
      ext.toLowerCase() == 'png'
    ) {
      this.coverPicFileType = true;
    } else {
      window.alert(this.alertType);
      this.coverPicFileType = false;
    }

    if (this.coverPicFileType) {
      this.convertFile(this.selectedCoverPic).subscribe((base64) => {
        this.coverPicBase64 = base64;
      });

      this.coverPicOnHold = true;
    }
  }
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="col-75">
      <div class="dropzone">
        <p>
          <a (click)="fileDropRef.click()"
            >Upload a file</a
          >
          or drag and drop
        </p>
        <input
          type="file"
          #fileDropRef
          id="fileDropRef"
          multiple
          (change)="onCoverPhotoSelected($event)"
          style="display: none"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
```

**I want to limit my drag and drop to ...**

On page it looks like this: (the dragarea is everything inside the dotted grey border on the right side of label Cover photo).
[image]

Thanks to everyone for your help. I am a little bit lost as I am not sure, how to fix that. Thanks again